# How to alter incorrect Join type generated by Views?

Tags: 7, views

I am suffering from a bug in Views 7.x-3.11 detailed [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1786790) in relation to filter groups. Views incorrectly adds INNER JOINs when LEFT joins would be correct.

I am trying to alter the $query object using the code ( this approach is not based on any documentation, but simply a guess ):

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if($view->name == 'my-view' && $view->current_display == 'my-display') {
    $query->table_queue['field_data_field_listing_type']['join']->type = 'LEFT';
  }
}
```

However this change causes the View to generate an ajax error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::build_join in sites/all/modules/views/plugin/views_plugin_query_default.inc on line 1313".

Any assistance?

Answer (score 1):

Complete operator error.  For the benefit of anyone else who encounters this error check your fieldname.  In my case I had misspelt the fieldname ['field_data_field_listing_type'] so it was generating a new incompleted entry in the table_queue array.